# The browser prints only one page of my website with less contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I'm working on a website that has long content in its main `div`, there is a vertical scroll in the div. However, when I try to print the website using browser print. only one page appears and most of the data is missing.

PS: I tried all possible solutions with `@media print { ... }`, and css styling.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code? Or a fiddle?

Comment: please add some information

Comment: @jsHero Der Vampyr

attached image described the issue. 
In it, the scrollable area contains a lot of data, when I try to print the page, only the shown area printed and I can't get the other part of scrollable area that not scrolled as pages.

Comment: on media print you just set the height of the scrollable area such that scrollbars are not their ,that should solve your problem .

Comment: Check out the answers here http://bit.ly/1yytAuw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use overflow-y:visible in the print media query.

```
    @media print {
  #mainLayout {
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: visible;
            overflow-x: visible;
        }
}
```